# How to take care of an antique wood cabinet

Tags: wood-repair, refinishing

I have an antique cabinet that my grandfather built decades ago and I want to preserve it.

I don't think he has done anything to preserve the wood so I should probably do some work on it. I would like to know what species of wood it is made from (if it is easily distinguishable from the picture).

I would also like to know what can be done to take care of it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should be clearer about what your question is. You want to "preserve" it. What does that mean, exactly, as this item already is preserved. I mean, it's lasted decades already, and could easily be cleaned up with soap and water. Assuming you mean you want to refinish this piece in some way. How far do you want to go with a refinish? What is your skill level, and what tools do you have, and how much work are you willing to put into it?

Comment: Also, check out the [tour] if you have not already. SE sites are a little different than threaded forum sites, in that you want to stick to a single question. So, _technically_ your question about identifying the wood used should be a separate question. This is to encourage good, complete answers. Also, I suspect identifying the wood used will require a totally different set of photos. You are encouraged to [edit] this question and make sure you ask a single question and provide all the necessary details to attract good answers.

Comment: Note that it was, and is, very common for the inside of solid wood cabinets to not be finished at all. So, if you are specifically asking about the unfinished interior know that this is sort of expected, and the years of aging have given the wood a patina that, again, _is_ a completely reasonable finish in many cases. So, make sure you tell us exactly what you have in mind for this cabinet, and what you mean by "preserve".

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  Please note that , in general, species identification is not within the scope accepted for Woodworking Stackexchange since it is so easy to be mislead by a picture..

Comment: *"I don't think he has done anything to preserve the wood"* The paint is a protective coating. Paints actually provide far better protection for wood than any other basic coating, *far* superior to varnish or lacquer for example The interior is likely completely unfinished, which is both normal and appropriate because it doesn't really need anything to protect it. These surfaces are hidden from light and don't see much direct contact or abrasion. The cabinet looks like it was very well made by the way, kudos to your grandfather!

Comment: *"I would also like to know what can be done to take care of it?"* You could clean it if you want, but from what I can see in the photos it's fine as-is for the time being. If you want to add a modicum of extra protection after cleaning you can wax it (using a paste wax ideally, not a liquid wax product which may contain oils) but this is by no means essential. And it will increase the gloss, which may not be desirable.

Comment: As for the wood used, as mentioned already we can't formally answer this as it's off-topic for the SE. But we try to help in the Comments where we can. And here it's literally impossible to tell from the photos — for many of the major pieces the wood largely looks like a uniform brown, so it could be nearly anything. We can't even tell if it's hardwood or softwood. And some of the back pieces look like they're different material (and possibly plywood, not solid wood, which is fairly normal for secondary pieces within a cabinet).

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty clear from the picture that the species of wood used here is known colloquially as "What Ihave Lyingaround" wood. A hard-soft-hard-softwood from west-central-eastern North America. I don't know the Latin name for it. Similarly, that paint colour is definitely the famous "Don't Waste The Left Over Green" found in the bottom 1/6th of paint cans throughout the last century.

Comment: @jdv, LOL, yes.

Answer (score 2):

If it was me, I'd dunk it in some paint stripper (or brush the stripper on) to rid it of that green color<sup>*</sup> then repaint it to match the room I was going to put it in. My Mother-in-Law would hang me for that, though, as she *loves* green of all shades, so that may not be your course of action.

If you're not going to strip it, a good dish-soap and water scrubbing may be all this needs to make it look as good as the day your gramps finished it. Use a *sponge* not a scrub pad unless there's a particularly stubborn area - the Scotch-Bright™ type scrub pads are likely to take the paint off, particularly if it's thin in places. **Note** you're not doing the dishes here - you don't need to *soak* down the wood, just get some warm, slightly soapy water, dunk the sponge, squeeze most of the water out, and gently rub the cabinet to get the gunk off. When it's clean, repeat with clear water to get rid of the soap, and pat it dry with paper towel or a shop towel, then let it sit out to dry. Soaking the wood is bad, lightly moistening it to lift the accumulated cruft is just fine.

Also, unless the "catch" piece of wood above the right-hand door is the way Grandpa originally built the cabinet, I'd consider replacing that with a magnetic catch on the inside, just to clean up the look a bit.

Once you've refurbished it to your desired state, dust it regularly, give it a gentle soap and water bath as necessary, try not to knock into it with heavy, pointy things, and pass it along to the next generation when the time comes.

<sup>*</sup>As noted by jdv in the comments, do be aware that there may be lead in that paint if it was applied before 1970 (or so) in the US. It was roughly that time-frame when lead was banned from paint. If you use a *chemical* paint stripper, you shouldn't have to be particularly concerned about it - the lead will remain in the liquid/gel and be disposed of when you throw it out. If you use a mechanical method (sanding, scraping) to remove the paint, you'll kick some/a lot of it in the air (especially sanding) and make small particles. These are the ones that are dangerous, so some common sense precautions are applicable.

Comment: That paint has lead in it for sure. Recommend _careful_ removal, or just paint over it.

Comment: Also, a cabinet like this deserves a good old ball-catch closure that matches the meaty doors. Lots of room there for a nice positive latch on the edge of the outer door.

Comment: @jdv, the lead warning is perhaps appropriate to be fair, but the thing has to be much older than I'm guessing it is for lead paint to be likely, or a certainty. Even at that, stripping makes the lead a non-issue. If sanding it is a worry of course, but modest single exposures to lead-containing dusts aren't of great concern to healthy adults....... if dust containing lead were an imminent health risk everyone old enough to have been around in the era of leaded gasoline would be very sick, or dead.

Comment: Added a note about possible lead contamination, just to be thorough.

Comment: @Graphus, it's about a total lifetime load, and you have no way of knowing who you might be exposing. Hence my use of the word _careful_. I'm puzzled why you would think this item has to be that much older for it to have to be in the lead-paint era. Lead paint was phased out in the early-to-mid 70s in North America, and was in private use nearly until the early 80s. Remember that the symptoms associated with extreme lead poisoning might be obvious, but it has been proven that lower levels of exposure are not as easily identifiable while still having a detrimental affect.

Comment: In some ways, the lead problem is similar to the fetal-alcohol problem. There are obvious symptoms but when you look closely there are less identifiable behavioural, mental, and health issues with even lower levels of exposures, depending on the age. Plainly put, if you buy old painted furniture, or have a house that was maintained before the 80s, get some lead testers and use them. I've yet to find someone in similar circumstances who has not found lead on some part of their house or refinished furniture, at least where I live.

Comment: And since we cannot control the level of exposure in our immediate environment, keeping on top of the amount I _can_ control isn't hysteria. It's common sense.

Comment: In short, one should _always_ test for lead in the paint of _any_ item you don't know the providence of. It's just prudent. "Low risk, high consequence" especially when talking about stuff that is to be refinished or used indoors, or around children. And it's not like testing is onerous. It is literally a 10s test.

Comment: @jdv, no point in us debating this here but single exposures to low levels of lead-containing dust do in fact present almost no risk to a healthy adult. [It is longer-term exposure that is a major concern, and of course exposure in children as I think you know.] In part this is because, unlike mercury, lead doesn't accumulate in the same way *and can easily be leached from the body if needed*. The right menu choices in a Thai or Mexican restaurant are enough!

Comment: @Graphus, I agree with your main statement that _single exposure_ is not something to panic about, _but_ we don't know under what circumstances this item would be refinished. Once the damage is done, it is done. As I said, low probability, high consequence. I'm a bit astonished about your assertion that lead does not accumulate in the body for _years_, as it is scientifically proven to do so, and does so more when overall nutrition is low (& other factors) There are too many variables we cannot control for, and the consequences can be so high, that it is mere prudence to treat it with respect.

Comment: @jdv, doesn't accumulate *in the same way*. Important distinction. The fact that you can leach lead from the body with a mere dietary hack is clearcut proof that it's not in any way like mercury, as a good comparison point. **Edit:** I'm pro safety, as I hope you realise from many of my Answers and Comments. So I'm not in any way suggesting that one should be cavalier about creating a situation where you will be exposed to lead-containing dusts. Merely pointing out that if such an exposure to occurred (low level, single incident) it would not be a concern for a typical healthy adult.

Comment: Sure, not like mercury, agreed. But it _does_ accumulate to some extent, and it does harm the youngest and most economically disadvantaged first. The "leaching" process used (medical chelation) has its own problems, so you'd do best to avoid having to go through it. Not to mention that you have to _know_ that you've been exposed. Historically, the most disadvantaged didn't know they were exposed to low-levels of lead.

Comment: This, of course, makes any medical mitigation useless. When discussing toxicity we _have_ to also discuss more than just the LD-50 on an individual, or an ideal case of small exposures. Lead is a _social_ problem, so the solutions around mitigation have to include solutions that take that into account. So, prudence suggests we use the simple lead test on anything of this vintage before considering refinishing.

Comment: Gentlemen! It seems that we all agree, in general terms, that lead is bad for the body and that one should avoid inhaling or ingesting it. The point was well made that this paint likely contains lead and that some amount of care and thought should go into its removal. Let's leave it to the OP (and other readers) to determine for himself what precautions she should take when stripping paint, and, if more input is needed, ask a new question. This has wandered far enough off-topic.